# PHP custom ordering array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

An array arrives with some or all of the following values, in any order. What's the best way to order them in ascending size order? So starting with small and ending with XXL. I can usort but am a bit lost as to how the elements should be ordered in my user defined function

```
Small
XXL
Medium
Large 
XL
```

EDIT: left out some info so created new question [Custom ordering array with key / value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014743/custom-ordering-array-with-key-value-pairs)

EDIT2: Full code

```
print_r($sizes);
$sorted_sizes = $this->sort_sizes(array_unique($sizes));
print_r($sorted_sizes);

function sort_sizes($sizes)
{
    return uasort($sizes, array($this, 'cmp'));
}

function cmp($a,$b)
{
    $sizeArray = array( 'Small' => 0, 'Medium' => 1, 'Large' => 2, 'XL' => 3, 'XXL' => 4); 
    return $sizeArray[$a] - $sizeArray[$b];
}
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [66-507cddcd16d9786abafccfa78b19acf8] => XL
    [64-507cddcd16d9786abafccfa78b19acf8] => medium
    [65-507cddcd16d9786abafccfa78b19acf8] => large
    [63-507cddcd16d9786abafccfa78b19acf8] => small
)
```

and print_r($sorted_sizes) just gives output "1"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer according to full code**

The first issue here is that you're returning the result of `uasort()`:

```
function sort_sizes($sizes)
{
    return uasort($sizes, array($this, 'cmp'));
}
```

That's wrong, because `uasort()` does not return the sorted array. It modifies the same variable that you pass as a parameter, and returns a boolean value. That's why you see `1` as output.

Make the method accept `$sizes` by reference:

```
function sort_sizes(array &$sizes)
{
    uasort($sizes, array($this, 'cmp'));
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
print_r($sizes);
$sorted_sizes = array_unique($sizes);
$this->sort_sizes($sorted_sizes);
print_r($sorted_sizes);
```

Here's your `cmp()` method, with added support for case-insensitive sorting:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $sizes = array('small' => 0, 'medium' => 1, 'large' => 2, 'xl' => 3, 'xxl' => 4);
    return $sizes[strtolower($a)] - $sizes[strtolower($b)];
}
```

---

**Old answer**

Try this. Use `uasort()` instead if you want to [maintain key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014743/custom-ordering-array-with-key-value-pairs):

```
function sort_sizes($a, $b) {
    // Map the sizes to an ordered sequence of ints
    static $sizes = array('small' => 0, 'medium' => 1, 'large' => 2, 'xl' => 3, 'xxl' => 4);

    // Find the difference, using the sizes as keys to the above array
    return $sizes[strtolower($a)] - $sizes[strtolower($b)];
}

$arr = array('Small', 'XXL', 'Medium', 'Large', 'XL');

print_r($arr); // Before sorting
uasort($arr, 'sort_sizes');
print_r($arr); // After sorting
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Small
    [1] => XXL
    [2] => Medium
    [3] => Large
    [4] => XL
)
Array
(
    [0] => Small
    [2] => Medium
    [3] => Large
    [4] => XL
    [1] => XXL
)
```

Comment: In case of an associate array you might want to use `uasort`. An example: http://www.ideone.com/FjxgY

Comment: How do I call sort_sizes in usort($arr, 'sort_sizes'); if these are methods in a class? Usually I call a function via $this->sort_sizes but if I pass that as an unquoted parameter I get a Undefined property: Products::$sort_sizes_do error.

Comment: @stef: Instead of `usort($arr, 'sort_sizes');`, do `usort($arr, array($this, 'sort_sizes'));`

Comment: Ok great. I'm making a second question since the input array actually has key/value pairs and the relation between the two needs to be maintained. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014743/custom-ordering-array-with-key-value-pairs

Comment: @stef: codaddict's comment already answers that question: use `uasort()` instead of `usort()`.

Comment: @BoltClock this method gives me Undefined index: medium

Comment: @stef: I amended my answer to support case insensitive sorting.

Comment: Yep fixed the notice, no big deal. However the final output is just '1' now.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort):

```
$orderIndex = array_flip(array('Small','Medium','Large','XL','XXL'));
$arr = array('Small','XXL','Medium','Large','XL');
array_multisort(array_map(function($val) use ($orderIndex) { return $orderIndex[$val]; }, $arr), $arr);
```

Here [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) is used with an [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) to build an array of the “weight” of each value in `$arr`. That array is then used to order the values in `$arr`.

This is basically the same [as BoltClock suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014549/php-custom-ordering-array/4014605#4014605) just with doing the comparison on the already calculated “weights”.

Answer (score 1):

Do the sorting in two phases. First, convert text to a convenient numeric value. In this moment you should decide if "L" and "Large" map to the same value or not. Then reorder the array based on those numeric conversions.