# Custom ordering array with key / value pairs

Tags: php

The following array arrives:

```
Array
(
    [66-507cddcd16d9786abafccfa78b19acf8] => XL
    [64-507cddcd16d9786abafccfa78b19acf8] => medium
    [65-507cddcd16d9786abafccfa78b19acf8] => large
    [63-507cddcd16d9786abafccfa78b19acf8] => small
)
```

How can I order the values of the array in ascending size order in such a way that the key / value relation is maintained? The array values may be some or all of the following

```
Small
XXL
Medium
Large 
XL
```

Comment: See codaddict's comment on my answer to your other question. In fact, it probably would have been better for you to edit your other question to include this instead, so I can adjust my answer accordingly as well.

Comment: [Link to aforementioned other question for those uninitiated.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014549/php-custom-ordering-array)

Answer (score 1):

If your sorting needs are more complex than [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) or [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) as previously suggested, then write a function to plug into [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `uasort`:

```
function sizeSorter($a, $b) {
    // customize as needed
    $comp = array_flip(array('xxxs', 'xxs', 'xs', 's', 'small', 'm', 'medium', 'l', 'large', 'xl', 'xxl', 'xxxl'));
    return $comp[strtolower($a)] - $comp[strtolower($b)];
}

uasort($array, 'sizeSorter');
```

Live example:

> http://codepad.org/vxcN29sO

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort your values alphabetically, that's what [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) is for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use asort. I copied this fomr the php website

asort — Sort an array and maintain index association

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php